# UICollectionView reload on iOS 6 and iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am working app which uses UICollectionView. This app runs very well on iOS 6 but fails to run it on iOS7. I debug a lot and come to conclusion that reload method of UICollectionView doesn't work on iOS 7.

Is there any reason behind this?

here are the steps of my app functionality where I found issue.

1. MyCollectionViewCell frame get changed (This is subclass of UICollectionViewCell)
2. Reload collection view.
3. iOS 6 works well (Here invalidate layout gets called internally then "cellAtRowOfindexpath:" i.e. collection view data source methods gets call)) /

   iOS 7 doesn't work reload method (Here only invalidate layout gets called but not "cellAtRowOfindexpath:" i.e. collection view data source method).

Thanks in advance...

Comment: What layout are you using? is it Flow Layout or a custom one? I'm using a few collection views on iOS 7 and had no issues so far. maybe a sample code or a project can help.

Answer (score 0):

the number of cells/sections in the datasource never changed, So you have to reload the visible content on the screen By calling below function of collection view

```
[_collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:[_collectionView indexPathsForVisibleItems]];
```

put above line just after

```
[_collectionView reloadData]
```

Hope your problem will be solved.